# Complex align of images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align 3 images on a website's welcome page.

The company logo (500*500) must be centered horizontally AND vertically no matter what the size of the page will be.

On the right and left sides of the main logo I have 2 flags (96*96) which indicate to which language on the site the user will be redirected to.

I would like that the horizontal center of the logos are all centered even though they don't have the same vertical size (500 for the main logo and 96 for the flags) like if there was a horizontal line passing through the middle of all of them.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: if you have a tried please share your code in jsfiddle

Comment: what did you tried ???

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#horizon {
display: block;
height: 1px;
left: 0;
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 50%;
width: 100%;
}

#content {
height: 500px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -250px;
position: absolute;
top: -250px;
width: 500px;
}
```

I've been using this snippet of code for years, basically it positions the #content in the absolute centre of the page (obviously the figures will need to be massaged for your app).

After that, added the two further images either side should be straight foward . . .

Comment: Ok, got it running, thanks, for my information what is the use of the horizon since it does not get used, right ?

Comment: Now I come to think of it (I copied this code from an old site of mine), originally #content sat inside #horizon to achieve a vertical centering as well as horizontal...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, could you be more specific, I'm really strating with CSS and I'm more often lost that anything else :)

At the moment I have this....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta keywords="lamera", "h-racing", "gentleman driver", "course", "endurance" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>H-Racing</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url(/images/fond.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
}
.horizon {
display: block;
height: 1px;
left: 0;
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 50%;
width: 100%;
}
.contentlogo {
height: 500px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -250px;
margin-top: 250px;
position: absolute;
width: 500px;
}
.contentflagfr {
height: 96px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -446px;
margin-top: 452px;
position: absolute;
width: 96px;
}
.contentflaguk {
height: 96px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: 350px;
margin-top: 452px;
position: absolute;
width: 96px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/fr/index.php"><img src="../images/france.png" align="left" class="contentflagfr"/></a>
<img src="/images/logo.png" class="contentlogo"/>
<a href="/en/index.php"><img src="../images/uk.png" align="right" class="contentflaguk"/></a>
</body>
</html>
```